# AlarmManager срабатывает не в заданное время

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-alarm-manager

Проблема в том, что если я укажу менеджеру время пробуждения, допустим 07:00, а сейчас 22:25, то он сработает мгновенно, если укажу 23:00, то он сработает в заданное время. Как сделать так, чтобы он сработал завтра в 07:00?
Я понимаю, что самый простой способ это указать явно переменной `calendar`, но есть ли другие варианты, если я, допустим, "не знаю" какой сейчас день и год?

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePickerHours);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePickerMinutes);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не можете не знать текущее время системы, в т.ч. потому, что тогда и alarmManager не сможет сработать, т.к не будет знать когда ему срабатывать.

Вам надо сравнивать заданное вами значение времени с текущим и, если оно меньше (т.е. уже прошло) то надо прибавить сутки к заданному времени.

Answer (score 0):

сalendar.set()- установи дату и время

должен быть метод setWhen(calendar.getTimeInMillis) у AlarmManager. Попробуй его